# return data as column from other table

Tags: sqlite, join

Working with two SQLite tables, example below. I want to be returned the name of the person, and their age range, not the rangeId.

```
SELECT t1.ageRange, t2.name   
FROM Table1 t1   
INNER JOIN Table2 t2  
WHERE t1.rangeId = t2.ageRangeId
```

```
.  
.  //This code does what I want, but is really inefficient and isn't scalable  
.

Table1   _____________//table name  
rangeId : ageRange__  //column names  
1 : 0 - 16  ___________//sample data  
2 : 17 - 28  
3 : 29 - 50  
4 : 50+  
.  
Table2  
name : ageRangeId  
John : 2  
David : 3  
Karl : 2  
Ben : 1
```

Comment: I don't think there's a better way.

Comment: use ON  insted of where

Comment: ... oh, except for that obviously ;-$

Comment: Both the join and the subquery are equally efficient and scalable. What specific problem do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The INNER JOIN syntaxe is

```
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.key=Table2.key
```

I made a fiddle. Here is what you want :

```
SELECT t1.ageRange, t2.name   
FROM Table1 t1   
INNER JOIN Table2 t2  
ON t1.rangeId = t2.ageRangeId
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10c60f/2

The problem is that your example is simple and the way you did it can't be improved. You just join 2 little tables. There're different way to do this but they are all equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT t2.name, t1.ageRange
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON (t1.rangeId = t2.ageRangeId)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to a join would be a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
SELECT name,
       (SELECT ageRange
        FROM Table1
        WHERE rangeId = Table2.ageRangeId
       ) AS ageRange
FROM Table2;
```